# Getting ServerError: java.lang.AssertionError when executing user defined aggregate function in cassandra db

Tags: cassandra

I have implemented user defined aggregate function ***average*** in my cassandra db as described in the link https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avgState ( state tuple<int,bigint>, val int ) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS tuple<int,bigint> LANGUAGE java AS
'if (val !=null) { state.setInt(0, state.getInt(0)+1); state.setLong(1, state.getLong(1)+val.intValue()); } return state;';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avgFinal ( state tuple<int,bigint> ) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS double LANGUAGE java AS
'double r = 0; if (state.getInt(0) == 0) return null; r = state.getLong(1); r/= state.getInt(0); return Double.valueOf(r);';

CREATE AGGREGATE IF NOT EXISTS average ( int )
SFUNC avgState STYPE tuple<int,bigint> FINALFUNC avgFinal INITCOND (0,0);

User defined aggregate function ***average*** works fine when the query returns at least one row for aggregation. But when there is no row returned for aggregation, the query outputs the error **ServerError: java.lang.AssertionError**

Requesting help.

My cassandra db version is [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Thanks in Advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer at the link : https://community.datastax.com/questions/9891/getting-servererror-javalangassertionerror-when-ex.html